# Moving Files in SQL as Blob (Filestream)

Tags: sql-server, blob, filestream

I have setup both of my Servers with Filestream for T-SQL access (and my DBs).
I created tables on both Servers:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
[UI] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFAULT (newid()),
      [Data]      [varbinary](max)FILESTREAM NULL)
```

I am inserting my File (.bak File, Backup of my DB 5,2GB) as:

```
INSERT table ( Data )
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'F:\myDB.bak', SINGLE_BLOB) AS X
```

I insert it on a same table over Linked Server in my 2nd Server. Then i want to create my .bak file again:

```
DECLARE @fPath varchar(400) = 'F:\myDB.bak' 
, @init int,
@data varbinary(max)

SELECT @data = (Select data from mytable)

EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @init OUTPUT; -- An instace created
  EXEC sp_OASetProperty @init, 'Type', 1;   
  EXEC sp_OAMethod @init, 'Open'; -- Calling a method 
  EXEC sp_OAMethod @init, 'Write', NULL, @data; -- Calling a method 
  EXEC sp_OAMethod @init, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @fPath, 2; -- Calling a method 
  EXEC sp_OAMethod @init, 'Close'; -- Calling a method 
  EXEC sp_OADestroy @init; -- Closed the resources
```

But my File only comes out as 1,6GB. and after trying to restore it i get:

> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 9 RESTORE DATABASE is terminating
>   abnormally. Msg 3287, Level 16, State 1, Line 9 The file ID 1 on
>   device 'F:\myDB.BAK' is incorrectly formed and can not be read.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That all looks pretty complicated.  Can you use FileTables instead?  Then you would have direct filesystem access to the files. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filetables-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Problem is i can not use FILETABLE because many of the servers i am working on are still 2008 R2. It works with `[varbinary](max)` without having FILESTREAM enabled but i have Files that are larger than 2GB

Comment: What are you really trying to acomplish?

Comment: As David asked... what do you really want to do with this ? You may not be using the best approch to get your problem fixed...

Comment: please see [help/merging-accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: I am trying to move my Backupfile through a Linked Server. There is no Option to move it through the Windows File System.

Comment: "There is no Option to move it through the Windows File System" then you should fix that.

Comment: well no... that is not an option...